# Identity user after they have logged in .net 4.5

Tags: c#

I need some help here, I am trying to identify a user after they have logged in. My code works ok apart from the where clause.
How do you identify a user, I am basically trying to say where UserName == loginName give me the full record.
Then from the record I can pull out the GarageID, any help or pointers much appreciated.

```
  private void FindGarageID()
    {
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity;

        string loginName = identity.Name;

        using (tyrescannerdatabaseEntities dbcontext = new tyrescannerdatabaseEntities())
        {

            garage = (from r in dbcontext.AspNetUsers

                          where r.UserName == loginName

                          select r).FirstOrDefault();

            if (!garage.GarageID.Equals(null))
            {
                garageID = (int)garage.GarageID;
            }
            else
            {
                garageID = 1;
            }
       }
```

Comment: So a bit more information would be nice.  If you are using identity I assume this is an internal site?

Comment: eh no its a website, am I using the wrong code?

Comment: WindowsIdentity is used when you are using active directory to validate your users.  If this is a public website, then when the user logs in, put there username in session and then use that in your query.

Comment: ok thanks will try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I would do this.  I would create a static class called Session.  This just encapsulates the accessing of session variables for me.

```
public static class Session
{
      public static string UserName
      {
           get { return (JsonWhereClause)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]; }
           set { HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = value; }
      }

}
```

Then when the user logs in, I would do this.

```
 Session.UserName = ""//User inputed username
```

This would then make your code be this.

```
private void FindGarageID()
{
    string loginName = Session.UserName;

    using (tyrescannerdatabaseEntities dbcontext = new tyrescannerdatabaseEntities())
    {

        garage = (from r in dbcontext.AspNetUsers

                      where r.UserName == loginName

                      select r).FirstOrDefault();

        if (!garage.GarageID.Equals(null))
        {
            garageID = (int)garage.GarageID;
        }
        else
        {
            garageID = 1;
        }
   }
```

Note that the Session will only be available on the webserver, so if you have a service you would need to pass the username to the service.